# __FILE__ shows whole path with filename

Tags: c, linux, makefile

i am using

```
DPRINTF(ERROR_LEVEL,"ERROR: error found at file: %s line: %d",__FILE__,__LINE__);
```

it printf like this

```
ERROR: error found at file: /home/jeegar/ full path to that file/main.c line: 102
```

here i just want to print only

```
ERROR: error found at file: main.c line: 102
```

i just want file name not whole path

well i m running this file with make file and in which i am using this mechanism

```
PATH_NOW              = $(shell pwd)
LIB                   =$(PATH_NOW)/../lib
```

when ever i need to access any file from lib folder i just include there

```
$(LIB)/main.c
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
DPRINTF(ERROR_LEVEL,"ERROR: error found at file: %s line: %d",__FILE__,__LINE__);
```

to:

```
DPRINTF(ERROR_LEVEL,"ERROR: error found at file: %s line: %d",basename(__FILE__),__LINE__);
```

Comment: Don't forget to `#include <libgen.h>` to prevent warnings!